# How can I deploy a graphql API with docker-compose in azure

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, docker-compose, graphql

I have problems trying to deploy a graphql API to Azure web apps (I don't know if it's the right place but here's my case)

### My expectation

I want to deploy a graphql API using a docker-compose file with azure-container-registry. I use docker for local development and everything is correct. In the docker-compose file I define my local enviroment variables, and in my node.js API I reference this variables using `process.env.{variable_name}`

### My problem

In production, I got a blank page (with no visible error log) when I was trying to access my currently deployed app link (For example https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/graphql)
[image]

Here's the stack of my graphql API: Apollo Server, Nodejs, Docker compose (I used apollo-server-express)

### What I tried

I used Azure pipelines to deploy the front-end repository of my application and configured a GitHub action too. So I decided to use the same logic with my backend repository.

I already deployed my mongodb using Atlas.

I put my docker-compose-prod.yml variables between ${ } symbols because I guess this is necessary for the azure pipelines to detect where I'm going to put my variables

This is how it looks like.

```yaml
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: <.....>
  imageRepository: 'myimagereposity'
  containerRegistry: 'mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile.dev'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  dockerComposeFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/docker-compose-prod.yml'
  projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        azureSubscription: 'Suscripcion developer 1(id-subs)'
        azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/id-subs/resourceGroups/proyecto-final/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/mycontainername"}'
        dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose-prod.yml'
        dockerComposeFileArgs: |
          DATABASE_URL=mongodb+srv://mydb-user:$(dbpassword)@cluster0.defvz.mongodb.net/$(dbname)?retryWrites=true&w=majority
          AWS_ACCESS_ID=$(AWS_ACCESS_ID)
          AWS_SECRET_KEY=$(AWS_SECRET_KEY)
          AWS_REGION=$(AWS_REGION)
          S3_BUCKET_NAME=$(S3_BUCKET_NAME)
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
        action: 'Build services'
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine 

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr/src/app 

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent 

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "debug" ]
```

This is my docker-compose-prod.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    container_name: 'saaga-api'
    restart: 'always'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile.prod'
    volumes:
      # - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      ORIGIN: 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net'
      PORT: 8080
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      AWS_ACCESS_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      AWS_REGION: ${AWS_REGION}
      S3_BUCKET_NAME: ${S3_BUCKET_NAME}
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9229:9229
    links:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Someone knows what I'm missing or what I'm doing badly? The app works well for the local environment, the problem is only in production.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs of the web app?

Comment: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you expose the ports 8080 and 9229 for the API application, but the Azure Web App only can expose one port from 80 or 443 to the outside. So if you do not use ports 80 and 443, you need to set the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` with the port that you want to expose to outside.

Comment: This seems to be the problem, I will try with different ports. Maybe that could do the trick

Comment: @Roberto If there is any news, please let me know.

Comment: I finally did it! I changed the port, but I also configured again the environment variables. I did the deploy again, and it works. I don't know if was a problem using azure containers, but when I created another web-app I choosed source code instead of Linux containers. Thanks for the help!